# Is it possible to store pattern of enum with associated value in array?

Tags: swift, enums

Let's say we have simple enum with message types:

```
enum MessageType {
    case audio
    case photo
    case text
}
```

There is `Handler` class which handles messages with specific types only:

```
class Handler {
    let allowed: [MessageType]

    init(_ allowed: [MessageType]) { self.allowed = allowed }

    func canHandle(_ messageType: MessageType) -> Bool {
        return allowed.contains(messageType)
    }
}
```

Basic usage example:

```
let handler = Handler([.audio, .photo])
print(handler.canHandle(.text)) // Prints false
```

I want to upgrade my `MessageType` and add associated value for some of message types.

```
class Audio {}

enum MessageType {
    case audio(Audio)
    case photo
    case text
}
```

Problem is that I can't store enum's pattern in `allowed` array for the future check in `canHandle`:

```
// error: '_' can only appear in a pattern or on the left side of an assignment
let handler = Handler([.audio(_), .photo])
```

Is it possible to resolve such case in a "clean" way?

- It's not possible to modify `MessageType` because it's in third-party library  (e.g. making arguments optional and passing `nil`)
- It's not possible to init `MessageType.audio(Audio)` with fake `Audio` because it could have private initializer
- I hope to avoid `switch`, `case let` or other hard-coded checks in `canHandle`

Any suggestions? Thanks

[image: do androids dream of electric enums]

Comment: Does your Handler class ever have to use the associated value in the audio case?  Or is it's job simply to check if can handle it?

Comment: @Ben It's used only for checking. There is `BasicHandler` where `canHandle` should been overridden

Comment: You could have a `Handler` initialiser that takes a `(MessageType) -> Bool` predicate and then use a `switch` statement on the caller side. Not pretty, but unfortunately there's no real simple way to check if a given enum with associated values is of a given case (ignoring the value) outside of pattern matching.

Comment: There have been a couple of recent SE pitches for improving the current situation for enums w/ associated values: https://forums.swift.org/t/automatically-derive-properties-for-enum-cases/10843 & https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-auto-synthesize-cases-for-enums/10075

Comment: @Hamish thanks for suggestion. I'm trying to avoid `switch` but It seems to be best solution for now. I hope some of pitches you have provided will be implemented in future versions of Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **If instantiating the enum with a default (or garbage) value isn't a big deal**

```
enum MessageType {
    case audio(String)
    case photo
    case text
}

protocol SneakyEquatableMessage {
    func equals(message: MessageType) -> Bool
}

extension MessageType: SneakyEquatableMessage {
    func equals(message: MessageType) -> Bool {
        switch (self, message) {
        case (.audio(_), .audio(_)),
             (.photo, .photo),
             (.text, .text):
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}

class Handler {
    let allowed: [MessageType]

    init(_ allowed: [MessageType]) { self.allowed = allowed }

    func canHandle(_ messageType: MessageType) -> Bool {
        return allowed.contains { $0.equals(message: messageType) }
    }
}
```

**Basic Usage**

```
let handler = Handler([.audio(""), .photo])
print(handler.canHandle(.text)) // Prints false
print(handler.canHandle(.audio("abc")) //Prints true
```

### **Default (or garbage) values are unrealistic**

This particular section is more specific in this context, but **ultimately you're going to have breakdown your enum somehow as of Swift 4.** So this is my suggestion: *Dependency Injection* of the *Factory Pattern* inside `Handler`.  This solves all of your problems pretty cleanly without having to touch switch within Handler or optionals.

```
enum DisassembledMessage {
    case audio
    case photo
    case text
}

protocol MessageTypeFactory {
    func disassemble(message: MessageType) -> DisassembledMessage
    func disassemble(messages: [MessageType]) -> [DisassembledMessage]
}

class Handler {
    let allowed: [MessageType]
    let factory: MessageTypeFactory

    init(allowed: [MessageType], with factory: MessageTypeFactory) {
        self.allowed = allowed
        self.factory = factory
    }

    func canHandle(_ messageType: DisassembledMessage) -> Bool {
        return factory
            .disassemble(messages: allowed)
            .contains { $0 == messageType }
    }
}
```

**Basic Usage**

```
let audioValue: Audio = //...
let audioMessage = MessageType.audio(audioValue)
let factory: MessageTypeFactory = //...
let handler = Handler(allowed: [audioMessage, .photo], with: factory)
print(handler.canHandle(.text)) // Prints false
print(handler.canHandle(factory.disassemble(message: audioMessage))) //Prints true
```

You may be asking: wait... you just created another enum (also this is just an example, you could convert it to whatever you want in that protocol).  Well I say: the enum you're using is from a library... see my notes section.  Also, you can now use that factory anywhere you need to break down the library type to something, including inside `Handler`.  You could easily expand the protocol  `MessageTypeFactory` to convert your enum to other types (hopefully behaviors) you've created, and basically just distance yourself from the library type when you need to.  I hope this helps clarify what I was getting at!  I don't even think you should store `MessageType` in your class.  You should store your own type which is some kind of mapped version of `MessageType`, like `DisassembledType`.

I hope this helps!

**Notes**

A few things:

- I'm sorry your soul is owned by a library, really.
- Use the Adapter Pattern.  [Clean C++](https://www.apress.com/us/book/9781484227923) is one of many places you
  can learn about it.  Don't pollute your entire code base with one of
  their types!  That's just a tip.
- I know you said you didn't want to use a switch... but you're working with enums...  At least it's within the enum!
- Use your own types! (Did I say that?)
- Use the Adapter Pattern! (Stop it.)

Comment: I didn't actually show it, but you should use the protocol in your function argument instead!  Stop passing around that library type =). I just left things as unchanged as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How could I instantiate `Handler` in your example? Btw, we could replace `SneakyEquatableMessage` with implementing `Equatable` for `MessageType`

Comment: @Leo Yes you could easily replace it with `Equatable.`  I just used a custom protocol because `Equatable` might be confusing for someone looking at your code later that an associated type within an enum is also part of that equivalent check.  Anyway, I'll develop my answer further and rename things give me a few minutes.

Comment: Wrapping enum inside of custom protocol is a good point, however it doesn't save from instantiating `MessageType` to fill `allowed` array.

Comment: @Leo yep I'm getting there.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Having copy of enum without associated values is not ideal but good enough as a temporary solution while waiting for swift to propose better approach. With that remark, I'll accept it as problem-solved.